# Trouble restoring accidentally moved Android drawable resource folder

Tags: android

I accidentally dragged the *drawable-hdpi* resource folder and moved it under the *menu* folder.  This left me with an empty *drawable-hdpi* folder with a red x remaining in its place as seen in the screen shot

[image]

Performing an Undo Move gave me an error saying the folder already exists in its current location.  I cannot drag it back under *res* as I get a similar error.

I was able to move the contents of the moved drawable folder to the one left in its original place, but the red x on it remains (after refreshing and restarting Eclipse)... which concerns me.

What does the red X mean? (note, this is different than the X you get when there are errors)

Anyone know what I can do to correctly restore the drawable folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing you can do is.

1. Browse into the workspace folder to your workspace folder. I mean File Explorer not in Eclipse. Close eclipse by the way. For example, if the workspace is `c:\workspace` and the project is `testproject`, you should be browsing `c:\workspace\testproject\res\menu\drawable-hdpi`
2. Copy all the contents from here and go back to `c:\workspace\testproject\res\drawable-hdpi` and paste them here.
3. Do the same with the `drawable-ldpi` folder. Copy contents from the folder under **menu** and put it in the `res\drawable-ldpi`.
4. Manually delete the drawable folders from the ones in the menu folder.
5. Start eclipse. Select your *Project* and press the <kbd>F5</kbd> or Right Click on the project and select **Refresh**.

If you are still left with errors, go to *Project Menu - > Clean*.

Let me know how things go.